# Magento get category attribute value in Topmenu.php

Tags: magento, menu, attributes, categories

I have created a custom category attribute.
Now i need to access it's value in the _getHtml() function from Topmenu.php.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?:)

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What version are you on? The answer will depend on whether you're on 1.7 or lower

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't be able to get that kind of data inside the TopMenu block, unless you make some changes.

The Navigation is built up using a generic tree structure which doesn't have an concept of what a category is, however this is built up elsewhere using the categories.

If you look inside Topmenu.php you will see where the Navigation is built up:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before', array(
    'menu' => $this->_menu
));
```

This will fire off an event, which has an observer attached which will build up the navigation items for us, which happens to be:

```
Model: Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer
Method: _addCategoriesToMenu()
```

You can then add your new attribute into the Node data, which will then be available inside Topmenu.php

Example:

```
$categoryData = array(
    'name' => $category->getName(),
    'id' => $nodeId,
    'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
    'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
    'my_attribute' => $category->getData('my_attribute') // Add our data in...
);
```

You should then be able to use this inside Topmenu::_getHtml()

```
echo $child->getData('my_attribute');
```

Comment: Thank you, i managed to get it working myself and forgot to post this here. But i hope this answer will help others who are trying to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 13):

Andrew's answer is the way i usually do it. However, it is important to note that if you are adding a custom attribute and if you want your store to work with and without the category flat tables enabled you need to make sure you have the following added to your code:

On your module's `config.xml`:

```
...
<frontend>
    <category>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                <my_attribute /><!-- your attribute code here -->
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </category>
</frontend>
...
```

That will make sure your attribute is loaded when the default category collection is created on `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree::_getDefaultCollection()`. Now, that works great when the store is set *NOT* to use the category flat tables. In case you want to use the flat tables, you will also need to add your attributes in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::_loadNodes`. Find the code below, where the select is created, and also add your attribute code there:

```
$select = $_conn->select()
    ->from(
        array('main_table' => $this->getMainStoreTable($storeId)),
        array('entity_id',
            new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.' . $_conn->quoteIdentifier('name')),
            new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.' . $_conn->quoteIdentifier('path')),
            'is_active',
            'is_anchor',
            'my_attribute')) /* add your attribute code here */
```

Only after that your attribute will show up on the Observer. Needless to say, do it using overwriting, never change the core code.

Comment: On top of Andrew's answer, I had to do the config.xml part shown here in order for this to work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I agree with Anthony on top of Andrew's answer we need to follow these changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete Gabriel Queiroz Silva answer :

instead of editing or overriding Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::_loadNodes method, you can use observer :

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before', array('select' => $select));
```

Comment: Nice of them to add this event it didn't exist when I wrote the answer... Indeed much better than overriding.